# Creating a sequential number on a SP online list

Tags: calculated-column-formula, splistitem, formula

I thought this would a fairly straight forward problem to solve. My client needs a unique identify number for a list item and it has to be seven digits long and sequential. I thought there would be a SP calculated value which could do this, but couldn't find one. Anyone have a formula which works? Or an alternative solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can write a workflow/microsoft flow on list item creation and populate a sequential number field within it based on the current list item ID.

Comment: Thanks @GaneshSanap I wanted to avoid a Flow if I could but all the solutions seem to pointing in that direction.

Comment: I think that is the best possible solution. you can create a simple 1-2 liner workflow to achieve this.